# Ajax: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Could anyone help me to wrap my head around this please? 
I’m trying to load WordPress post (custom post type) title/content in modal, but struggling to get it right. I’m quite new to php and ajax, so I have picked pieces of code from different tutorials and I try to assemble them all together.

So first I add a path to localize my script:

```
wp_localize_script( 'darkam_global', 'openpost', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
```

This is what my php function looks like:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_open_post', 'my_open_post' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_open_post', 'my_open_post' );

function my_open_post() {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $post = get_post($id);

    if($post){
        wp_send_json(array('post_title' => $post->post_title, 'post_content' => $post->post_content));
    } else {
        wp_send_json(array('error' => '1'));
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

and my jQuery:

```
( function( $ ) {
    var $modalTrigger = $('.js-modal-trigger');

    $modalTrigger.click( open_post_js );

    function open_post_js(id) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: openpost.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: id,
                action: 'open_post'
            },
            success: function( result ) {
                alert( result['post_title'] );
            }
        })
    }
} )( jQuery );
```

When I trigger the modal I get console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined. Also the alert result comes as "undefined".

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: What does `console.log(result);` return?

Comment: never use `alert()` for anything other than simple types (strings/numbers) - always use `console.log`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! console.log returns: `{error: "1"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php, you return a valid response of `{error:1}` - but you don't check for this in your jquery/ajax.
So it's probably failing in the php.

It *is* failing in the php because you're not passing an `id`.

In your `click` event wire up, you have:

```
$modalTrigger.click(open_post_js)
```

so clicking is the same as calling:

```
open_post_js();
```

yet your function signature is: `function open_post_js(id)` so it's expecting an `id`, eg:

```
open_post_js(1);
```

the `id` is then "passed" to the php, but because it's not passed to the javascript, php doesn't get it so falls over.

---

How do you fix this?  You need to pass an `id` to `open_post_js` *or* retrieve the `id` within `open_post_js`, eg:

```
function open_post_js() {
    var id=$(this).data("id");
    ...
}
```

then

```
<div class='js-modal-trigger' data-id="1">...</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explication @freedomn-m! I have just tried your suggestion and even though I don’t get Console error anymore, the console log still returns: `{error: “1”}` which probably means it’s not getting the post id from my php function. How could I fix that?

Comment: Check what you're *sending* to the php.  Looks like it's still not sending it in (and make sure you have a matching id for `get_post`

Comment: Actually it's not what I'm "sending", but what I should be "getting" from php, so I have changed the ajax type to GET and now it works like charm :) many thanks for all your help freedomn-m!! very appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how php handles parameters with `GET` vs `POST`. jquery will generally send the data in the `body` for a `POST` and in the url for a `GET`, so perhaps it's how you're reading the `POST` parameter.   If you're actually getting data, then better to use a GET anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP all looks good, the problem is that `id` in your JavaScript has no value assigned to it.

If the post ID is a data attribute on the element that is being clicked, then this should work (assuming the data attribute is called `data-id`):

```
( function( $ ) {
var $modalTrigger = $('.js-modal-trigger');

$modalTrigger.click( open_post_js );

function open_post_js() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: openpost.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: id,
            action: 'open_post'
        },
        success: function( result ) {
            alert( result['post_title'] );
        }
    })
}
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: ah, i didn't see that freedomn-m gave the same answer before me

Comment: Your help is still very appreciated! thanks for your input Simon!

Answer (score 0):

you try this code :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header( 'Content-Type: application/json;' );
if($post){
        wp_send_json(array('post_title' => $post->post_title, 'post_content' => $post->post_content));
    } else {
        wp_send_json(array('error' => '1'));
    }

        wp_die();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Quan Lee! I have managed to make it work with the accepted answer!